# Is there any way to see virtual memory usgae of a process per thread?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, memory

I am using RHEL 6.3(64-bit).
I made some changes in my multithreaded c/c++ program (used std:map for a specific requirement) and now initial virtual memory usage of my project has gone really high(around 900m). All the changes i made are guarded under a MACRO.

But after disabling the MACRO also i can not see any reduction in the virtual memory usage of my process.

So i have couple of question to ask.

1. Is there any way to find out which thread is consuming maximum virtual memory so that i can isolate the issue?
2. Why after disabling the macro virtual memory usage of my process is not going down?
3. The same project on 32-bit (RHEL-6.3) is taking really less virtual memory(around-150m).
   Almost 6 time lesser than 64 bit OS. why?

   I used top command to see virtual memory usage.

Comment: Why is that an issue? 0.9Gbytes is not that big! RAM is cheap. Is winning a few hundred megabytes worth several days of your time?

Comment: Are you using a revision control system (git, etc)?  If so, instead of just changing the macro actually sync back to an older version and try it.  If you see what you expect (low memory usage) then take a hard look at all the changes.  It not, start using one.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Of course compile all your program with debug info and warnings (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). With a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. [gcc-4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/)) on x86-64 you could also use the address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`)

When running (for tests) your program, you could use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) to query its address space. See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Try also [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/). Benchmark the *original* program (without any of yours modifications) on the 64 bits system.

<sup>I hope that you are using a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) like [git](http://git-scm.com/) on your code and your modifications.</sup>

By definition, the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) is common to all threads in your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). It is wrong to think that some particular *thread* is consuming memory - it is the process itself (i.e. any thread within the running program).

Perhaps you want to compile for the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).

BTw, each thread needs some memory (for stack, TLS, etc...) -which of course is visible to other threads, e.g. if you pass them some pointer inside it- and probably more on 64 bits than on 32 bits. How many threads do you have? (You probably should avoid having more than a dozen threads).

Comment: It is a just a initial virtual memory of my process. once it is up. and it is already filtered with valgrind. so no possibilty of leak, and why the problem is seen only on 64-bit. It is fine on 32-bit.

Comment: when i use pmap to see the address space. i see there are so many [anon] sections which are consuming most of the memory. But i am not able to figure out what exactly are they?

Comment: You don't show the output of `pmap` but they might be either used by implementation of  `malloc` or used for thread stack or TLS.

Comment: there are total 14 threads.and I can not reduce the no of threads because each thread is to serve specific purpose. With these similar threads it was working fine earlier. before i added these std:maps. and one more thing i observed is this problem in seen only in RHEL 6.3 system. On centos virtual memory usage are limited upto 250m.

Comment: What version of GCC -and of the C++ standard library- are you using? Consider upgrading the compiler -you could compile a GCC 4.9.1 from the source tarball

Answer (score 1):

64-bit code pointers are 8-bytes instead of the 4-bytes with 32-bit code.  So if your code uses lots of pointers, it is easy to double your heap size.  But that does not explain 6x bigger.

Sounds like you want to find out where your memory usage is going.  Google for "memory profiling" to find a tool.

I usually do memory profiling myself in my code

```
extern void * operator new( size_t, const char *, int );

#if 1
#define MY_NEW() new
#else
#define MY_NEW() new( __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#endif
```

Then change all use of 'new' to MY_NEW() in your code and change the #if when you want to enable memory profiling.  The operator new() calls malloc() and prints all 3 arguments to a file.  Then you make a script to slice and dice the data how ever you want.  Adding up all the allocations for one **FILE** & __LINE_ combination is usually a good place to start.  This method does not cover memory allocations in libraries (like STL).

Answer (score 1):

It is useful **to profile your program's memory consumption** with `valgrind --tool=massif` (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) and check its memory consumption before and after your modifications.

2) First, since you say "I used top command to see virtual memory usage" it is is quite useful to measure all memory in a process (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.not-measured) `valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes your-program` and check in a generated report where the peak of memory consumption was and stacktraces of biggest allocations.

2) Second, if on the step 1 you understand that the problem is in heap allocations check your application with `valgrind --tool=massif your_program` and compare memory consumption of processes before and after modification.

Answer (score 0):

you can try ps command grep for your process and list the threads 
ps -eLF , i couldn't recollect exactly to sort by memory usage.

try top -- command 'H' Option to show thread